# Capitalize first letter in each word in string with exceptions in Python

Tags: python

This is what I was given:

```
def cap(s):    
    lst = s.split()   
    res = ''     
    for word in lst:
        res = res + ' '+ word.capitalize()
    return res
```

How would I modify this to capitalize each letter in each word except words such as "and","is","it","if" etc.?

Comment: What did you try? What's the specific problem? (c)

Comment: so you know the length is at least 4 and you can use res{0:1].upper()

Answer (score 4):

Just filter out the words that shouldn't be capitalised:

```
no_caps_list = ["and", "is", "it", "if"]
def cap(s):    
    lst = s.split()   
    res = ''     
    for word in lst:
        if word not in no_caps_list:
            word = word.capitalize()
        res = res + ' '+ word
    return res
```

A cleaner version of the function can be written as:

```
def sensible_title_caps(str, no_caps_list = ["and", "is", "it", "if"]):
    words = []  
    for word in str.split():
        if word not in no_caps_list:
            word = word.capitalize()
        words.append(word)
    return " ".join(words)
```

Here we remove unneeded temporary variables and accept a list of words to not capitalise as a parameter (`no_caps_list`) with a sensible default value.

Or horrible obfuscated as a list comprehension:

```
def obfuscated_caps(str, no_caps_list = ["and", "is", "it", "if"]):
    return " ".join([w in no_caps_list and w or w.title() for w in str.split()])
```

Comment: They aren't useless variables, and obfuscating the code in a shorter list comprehension won't help the askers understanding of the problem.

Comment: Ok, there is a cleaner alternate version, but I don't see how doing a list comprehension would make it cleaner it would just be terrible obfuscated.

Comment: Yes.  I suppose with something this long, a list comprehension *would* be a little hard to read.  I'm satisfied ;)

Comment: Well I added a list comprehension anyway.

Comment: I would suggest `w if w in no_caps_list else w.capitalize()` instead of `[w, w.capitalize()][w not in no_caps_list]`.  It is the same number of characters, but is easier to read.

Comment: @zondo I will not be out golfed. Boolean funkyness removes 1 and switching from capitalise to title saves another 4

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work, but how would I add another exception saying if the first word in the title is "and" or "the" for example, it should be capitalized? I tried the word[0] concept, but it did not work.